# Using Grafana Variable in Prometheus Query

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I'm trying to use a variable at the start of one of my PromQL queries so I can return data based on the variable. Not sure if this is possible or not.

```
$variable_totalaccuracy_total
```

Expected to return the totalaccuracy for the variable but get back

> error:"parse error at char 1: unexpected character: '$'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use braces around the variable name:

```
${variable}_totalaccuracy_total
```